# How to change week day order in JTCalenderView in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jtcalendar

I am using `JTCalender` in project.I want to change the order of days displayed.The weekdays starts from `Monday` and end into `Sunday`.But i want the weekday from `Sunday` and end into `Monday`.Please guide me how can i implement.I am not able to understand how to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the firstDayOfWeek to whichever day you want while configuring the the JTAppleCalendar using the JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource Method:-

```
func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {
    let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2016 03 01")!
    let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2020 12 01")!
    var generateInDates: InDateCellGeneration = .forAllMonths
    var generateOutDates: OutDateCellGeneration = .tillEndOfGrid
    let firstDayOfWeek: DaysOfWeek = .sunday
    var numberOfRows = 6
    var testCalendar = Calendar.current

    let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate,
                                             endDate: endDate,
                                             numberOfRows: numberOfRows,
                                             calendar: testCalendar,
                                             generateInDates: generateInDates,
                                             generateOutDates: generateOutDates,
                                             firstDayOfWeek: firstDayOfWeek)

    return parameters
}
```

For JTCalendar, you can set the first day of the week using,

```
[_calendarManager.dateHelper.calendar setFirstWeekday:2]
```

replace "2" with whichever day you want.

Comment: I don't have this file in my code JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource

Comment: Which version of JTAppleCalendar are you using?

Comment: Latest from the github

Comment: Are you using JTAppleCalendar or JTCalendar?

Comment: if you using JTCalendar:
[_calendarManager.dateHelper.calendar setFirstWeekday:2]

Comment: likewise you can set whichever day of the week you want to start with, I am gonna add this to my answer too!